# oracledb chaining sql call using promises

Tags: node.js, database, oracle

I am pretty new to oracledb with NodeJS.
I want to do some mutiple sql call that are dependant. 
After the first sql query, I need to use the result to execute the second sql query,  and the result of the second query is used for the third.

I am trying to find some examples but failed to find any.

**EDIT 1** :  add code used to chain the sql queries.
before executing query sqltoExecute, I need to configure the connection by executing a query that set  "set role "    and then another one to "set package"
before executing my final query .

It only execute the first query that set the role and then nothing.

I am using on NodeJS 4.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.

```
exports.testChainingSqlQueries = function(config, sqlToExecute, callback) {

    if (config) {
        oracledb.getConnection(config)
            .then(function(conn){

                return conn.execute(
                        sqlQueries.sqlQuerySetRole()
                    )
                    .then(function(result){
                        console.log("Execution Succes : "+ sqlQueries.sqlQuerySetRole());
                        return conn;
                    })
                    .catch(function(err){
                        console.log("Error Executing  "+ sqlQueries.sqlQuerySetRole() );
                        return conn.close();
                    })
            })
            .then(function(conn){

                return conn.execute(
                        sqlQueries.sqlQuerySetPackage()
                    )
                    .then(function(result){
                        console.log("Execution Succes : "+ sqlQueries.sqlQuerySetPackage());
                        return conn;
                    })
                    .catch(function(err){
                        console.log("Error executing :  "+ sqlQueries.sqlQuerySetPackage());
                        return conn.close();
                    })
            })
            .then(function(conn){
                return conn.execute(
                        sqlToExecute
                    )
                    .then(function(result){
                        console.log("Execution Succes : "+ sqlToExecute);
                        callback(result, null);
                        return conn.close();
                    })
                    .catch(function(err){
                        console.log("Error executing : "+ sqlToExecute);
                        return conn.close();
                    })
            });

    } else {
        callback(null, {
            message: "Configuration is invalid ",
            config: config
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you include code that you have tried?  What environment are you trying to chain these sql queries in?

Comment: General node-oracledb questions can be asked at https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues

Comment: @FishStix I added the code I use to test the chaining.

Answer (score 0):

This is being discussed in your duplicate post: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/490