# How to use Node promises to return multiple result sets from Oracle

Tags: node.js, oracle, express

I have a Node/Express.js app connecting to Oracle using node-oracledb.

I am trying to return multiple queries to my view, however all of the examples I found in the Node-Oracle project are for a single query. https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples

There is various information online, but I couldn't find anything relating to this exact situation with an example I could get working. The closest I found is this question: [oracledb chaining sql call using promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797446/oracledb-chaining-sql-call-using-promises) which was taken to Github and not really answered.

The working code I have so far is:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var oracledb = require('oracledb');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  oracledb.getConnection()
  .then(function(connection) {
    return connection.execute(
      "SELECT note_id, name " +
        "FROM notes " +
        "WHERE note_id = :did",
      [1234]
    )
    .then(function(result) {
        res.render('index', { title: 'Express', table: result });
        return connection.close();
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        return connection.close();
    })
  })
  .catch(function(err) { console.log(err.message); })

});

module.exports = router;
```

How can I make this work with multiple queries and pass the results to the template?

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Express', table: result, table2: result2 });
```

Edit: My example is based on this: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/promises.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) or [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) promises library to do that .

Using `Bluebird` your code can be modified as shown below :

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    var getConnectionP = oracledb.getConnection();

    getConnectionP.then(function(connection) {

//Defining each query as a separate promise i.e query1P and query2P as both of them returns a promise

      var query1P = connection.execute(
          "SELECT note_id, name " +
            "FROM notes " +
            "WHERE note_id = :did",
          [1234]
        );

      var query2P = connection.execute(
          "SELECT note_id, name " +
            "FROM notes " +
            "WHERE note_id = :did",
          [5678]
        );

//Promise.join as the name says, gets resolved only when both the promises passed to it gets resolved and their results are available in the "spread" function callback as shown below : 

      Promise.join(query1P, query2P).spread(function (result, result2){
        res.render('index', { title: 'Express', table: result, table2: result2 });
        return connection.close();
      })
      .catch(function (err){
        console.log(err.message);
        return connection.close();
      });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Works great with Bluebird. The Promise.all() method worked as well, but took a second to process each time. I'm not sure if it was rebuilding the connection somehow (shouldn't be as it's pooled). This solution however was very quick.

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

If the order the queries execute in does not matter to you, you could use `Promise.all()` like so:

```
Promise.all([
    connection.execute(query1),
    connection.execute(query2),
    ...
])
.then((results) => {
    // => results is an array containing the results from each query
});
```